# Social Login with hybridauth Error

Tags: hybridauth

I always use the hybridauth library for social login via php, but when deploying to a new system, it always returns me this error:

```
    Oops, we ran into an issue! The authorization state [state=HA-87J6MLDU2T0F514HVCBSPWGXIZOEY3NRKQA9] of this page is either invalid or has already been consumed.
```

I already tested in different browsers and with social networks Google and Facebook, the script redirects to the social network and after logging in the error returned in the uri url is this up

Comment: Are you updating your redirect URIs on the Social Service developer portals to match the URL of the new system you are deploying to? If the URL changes, Google et. al. won't be able to access your redirect page to deliver the access tokens to your new server.

Comment: @sNiffer did u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After deleting all the Cookies everything works again.

**!** *The localhost has it's own Cookies in the browser, if you use a redirect.*

Additionally check if the callback points to the correct URL.